# boolean[] cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

In the class `SitoEratostenesaTest`, I have:

```
SitoEratostenesa myObj = new SitoEratostenesa(liczby[x]);

for(i=1; i<ilosc; i++)
{
    if(tab[i])
    {
        System.out.println((i+1)+" jest liczba pierwsza");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println((i+1)+" jest liczba zlozona");
    }
}
```

`boolean tab[]` was created in class `SitoEratostenesa`. How can I use this table in my condition?

Comment: What is `SitoEratostenesa` ?

Comment: SitoEratostenesa class must be having some getter and setters for tab variable. Can't you do myObj.getTab() ?
Or you can do  myObj.tab[i]

Comment: If it is a object variable you need to do something like this:
myObj.tab[i] (therefore it needs to be "public" ofc)

if it is a static variable you need to do something like this:
SitoEratostenesa.tab[i]

.Haven't coded in java for some time now, so this might be not 100% correct

Comment: Ok, "myObj.tab[i]" works, after creating field "tab" in SitoEratostenesa. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend to create a private field, and make getter and setter. It is more secure and better practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `SitoEratostenesa.tab` static?  If not you'll need to have a reference to an instance of `SitoEratostenesa` first.

Assuming that `SitoEratostenesa.tab` is accessible (public for example) to `SitoEratostenesaTest`, then the following should work:

```
 if(SitoEratostenesa.tab[i])
```

If `tab` isnt static, you'll need to access it by via an instance of SitoEratostenesa:

```
SitoEratostenesa yourInstance = ...

if(yourInstance.tab[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `myObj.tab[i]` to reference `tab[]` in you class. It has no reference with out your object.

Answer (score 0):

try to get the tab array from SitoEratostenesa by using `myObj.getTab()` and use it like `myObj.getTab()[i]` for example. If it is not there it might be reached directly, which is usually not a good practice, then it is called like `myObj.tab[i]`. If none of them are there, then you need to (if you are allowed to) make a getter method returning the `tab`.